# Change numbering according to field value by bash script

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a tab delimited file like this (without the headers and in the example I use the pipe character as delimiter for clarity)

```
ID1|ID2|VAL1|
1|1|3
1|1|4
1|2|3
1|2|5    
2|2|6
```

I want add a new field to this file that changes whenever ID1 or ID2 change. Like this:

```
1|1|3|1
1|1|4|1
1|2|3|2
1|2|5|2    
2|2|6|3
```

Is this possible with an one liner in sed,awk, perl etc... or should I use a standard programming language (Java) for this task. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F\| '$1$2!=a {f++} {print $0,f;a=$1$2}' OFS=\| file
1|1|3|1
1|1|4|1
1|2|3|2
1|2|5|2
2|2|6|3
```

Comment: +1. Just one question. Where do you set the delimiter or tab is the default one?

Comment: `-F\|` set it to `|` for input and `OFS=\|` set the same for output.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), though I'm sure you could figure out a 1-line [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
while IFS='|' read -r id1 id2 val1; do
  #Can remove next 3 lines if you're sure you won't have extraneous whitespace
  id1="${id1//[[:space:]]/}"
  id2="${id2//[[:space:]]/}"
  val1="${val1//[[:space:]]/}"
  [[ ( -n $old1 && $old1 -ne $id1 ) || ( -n $old2 && $old2 -ne $id2 ) ]] && ((count+=1))
  echo "$id1|$id2|$val1|$count"
  old1="$id1" && old2="$id2"
done < file
```

For example

```
> cat file
1|1|3
1|1|4
1|2|3
1|2|5    
2|2|6  
> ./abovescript
1|1|3|1
1|1|4|1
1|2|3|2
1|2|5|2
2|2|6|3
```

Replace `IFS='|'` with `IFS=$'\t'` for tab delimited

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still I had to accept Jotne's answer since it is easier to implement. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'FNR>1{print $0 FS (++a[$1$2]=="1"?++i:i)}' FS=\| file
```